# Typescript covers all case of list of string

Tags: typescript

How to cover all these cases in typescript. (*The order is not significant*)

1. ["A"]
2. ["B"]
3. ["C"]
4. ["A", "B"]
5. ["A", "C"]
6. ["B", "C"]
7. ["A", "B", "C"]

I have tried this but it does not work as expected

```js
type CASE = "A" | "B" | "C"
 
let cases: CASE[] = ["A", "A", "A"]; // this is not in the cases

let cases2: CASE[] = ["A", "B", "C", "A"]; // this is not in the cases
```

*I am not a native English speaker and don't know what these cases are called. So please be nice to me. I really appreciate it*

Edit: I found this one similar https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Number_of_k-combinations_for_all_k

Edit 2 (Use cases):
I have a `userRoles` property that is obtained from backend response

It included `'Operator' | 'Manufacturer' | 'Distributor'`

Some users can have

- a **single** role: `['Operator']` or `['Manufacturer']` or `['Distributor']`
- or **multiple** roles like `['Operator', 'Manufacturer']` or `['Operator', 'Distributor']` or `['Manufacturer', 'Distributor']` or `['Operator', 'Manufacturer', 'Distributor']`

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but I'd probably use a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set#using_the_set_object).

Comment: Is the order significant? Can you for example have `["C", "A"]`?

Comment: No. the order is not significant

Comment: Can you define your use case? Are you tring to defin type that will support all this type of data? Example explaining how will you use it will be helpful

Comment: This is not something that you can enforce with Typescript, other than specifying all the combinations in the type.

Comment: if order does not matter and you dont want to allow duplicates, use a Set.

Comment: @Sohan I added use cases

Comment: If the data is coming from the backend, why do you care if the type is wider than what the actual data is? It's not going to validate any external data anyway.

Comment: @Liap why not use Interface in this case ?

Comment: • @GuyIncognito is exactly right here, what code are *you* writing where you need the compiler to know for sure that no entry appears more than once in an array? It takes effort to add constraints to types, so what would that effort buy you? • Unions in TypeScript can only hold some number of members on the order of 10,000. If your `CASE` has more than a small handful of members, the type you're looking for will be a *huge* union.  How many members will `CASE` be likely to have?  Does it need to be an array? • Would `Set` work for you? If not, why not?

Comment: @GuyIncognito the answer is right. Can you make it as an answer in detail.

Comment: I have spent hours to try to find the best way to handle it, but it seems there is no way to do it except `specifying all the combinations in the type` like @GuyIncognito comment.

Comment: The point is, what is the actual problem you're trying to solve? What issues do you run into if you make the type just`type CASE = "A" | "B" | "C"`?